# Remove and change a character on string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array of strings. What I want is to remove from a string the character "," and the character "]" change it to "|".

string = 3.1321309062246026, 42.02829431948331],

and i want to get :
string = 3.1321309062246026, 42.02829431948331|

so i want to remove final "," but not the one in the middle. Also to change that ] to | . it has to change like this
3.1321309062246026,42.02829431948331|

Comment: Your question will likely get deleted because it’s so basic and general.  There are probably about 40 different ways to do what you’re talking about and they’ve probably all been covered in previous questions.  Having said that, if you want a fighting chance, I would start by making some crucial edits to your post.  To start with, ```print path[0]``` is not a valid name in Ruby.  Secondly, your value is impossible as it’s written.  I assume it should be a string and therefore wrapped in quotes but I can’t be sure.

Comment: Try `str.sub(/\],\z/,'|')`.

Comment: Provide actual Ruby code, please. Show both, the JSON input and the array of strings you’re generating out of it. Some explanation as of why you need this transformation might help, too.

Comment: Sorry, im new with this. Some one already showed me a solution in coments. I changed my question to be more valid and specific.

Comment: @CodrinM your strings are lacking delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
a="3.1321309062246026, 42.02829431948331],"
```

Code

```
p a.gsub(/\]/,"|").gsub(/,\z/,"")
```

Output

```
"3.1321309062246026, 42.02829431948331|"
```

Comment: Ty im rlly bad whit strings.